# Removing all characters in all file names in a folder up to the first space

Tags: windows, batch-file, batch-rename

I’m trying to write a .bat script to rename every file in a folder by removing all characters in all the file names up to the first space. I.e.:

`ABC defghij` -> `defghij`

And I need to automate this for all files in the folder. Is there a way to do this?

This is what I tried:

```
For %y in (directory) do (for /f “tokens=1,*” %%A in %y do ren %y” “%%B”)
```

Comment: Does `%%y` help? Also change these```”``` to these ```"```.

Answer (score 0):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
rem The following setting for the directory is a name
rem that I use for testing and deliberately includes spaces to make sure
rem that the process works using such names. These will need to be changed to suit your situation.

SET "sourcedir=u:\your files\t w o"
FOR /f "delims=" %%y IN ('dir /b /a-d "%sourcedir%\* *"') DO (
 FOR /f "tokens=1*delims= " %%b IN ("%%y") DO (
  IF EXIST "%sourcedir%\%%c" (ECHO Cannot RENAME "%%y" to "%%c" - already exists) ELSE (
    ECHO REN "%sourcedir%\%%y" "%%c"
  )
 )
)

GOTO :EOF
```

**Always verify against a test directory before applying to real data.**

Notes

- Your code has unbalanced quotes.
- Your code has "smart quotes" - plain quotes are required
- `%y` is correct from the command prompt, but `metavariables` like `%%y` need a double `%` in a batch file.

The required REN commands are merely `ECHO`ed for testing purposes. **After you've verified that the commands are correct**, change `ECHO REN` to `REN` to actually rename the files.

Fairly simple process - process a directory list matching the filemask of filenames only, tokenise as attempted, test whether rename is possible, report if it is not & rename if it is.

Answer (score 0):

Use PowerShell instead, it's much easier. The simplest method involves a regex replace

```
ls | ren -Ne { $_.Name -replace "^.+? " } -wi
# or
ls | ren -Ne { $_.Name -replace ".+? (.*)", '$1' } -wi
```

or the full command

```
Get-ChildItem -Filter "* *" | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name -replace "^.+? " } -WhatIf
# or
Get-ChildItem -Filter "* *" | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name -replace ".+? (.*)", '$1' } -WhatIf
```

`-WhatIf`/`-wi` is for dry running, remove it to do real renaming

`"^.+? "` matches the first "word" and the next space after it and remove, whereas `".+? (.*)"` captures the rest of the string and replace with what was captured